dnf with same repolist returning different responses
I am running centos9 stream on 2 machines beeline(works), zotac(no work).
managing both with ansible
they both have the same repo lists but searching for same packages has zotac not finding popular packages in it (pipx, xrdp, eza..)
[root@zotac ~]# dnf repolist
repo id                                                       repo name
appstream                                                     CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream
baseos                                                        CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS
copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:atim:lazygit                   Copr repo for lazygit owned by atim
crb                                                           CentOS Stream 9 - CRB
epel-cisco-openh264                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
epel-next                                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - Next - x86_64
extras-common                                                 CentOS Stream 9 - Extras packages
packages-microsoft-com-prod                                   packages-microsoft-com-prod
...
[root@zotac ~]# dnf info --refresh pipx
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:25 ago on Wed 09 Oct 2024 10:12:45 PM EDT.
Error: No matching Packages to list





[root@beelink ~]# dnf repolist
repo id                                                       repo name
appstream                                                     CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream
baseos                                                        CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS
copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:atim:lazygit                   Copr repo for lazygit owned by atim
crb                                                           CentOS Stream 9 - CRB
epel-cisco-openh264                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
epel-next                                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - Next - x86_64
extras-common                                                 CentOS Stream 9 - Extras packages
packages-microsoft-com-prod                                   packages-microsoft-com-prod
...
[root@beelink ~]# dnf info --refresh pipx

Last metadata expiration check: 3:09:05 ago on Wed 09 Oct 2024 07:08:29 PM EDT.
Installed Packages
Name         : pipx
Version      : 1.2.1
Release      : 1.el9
Architecture : noarch
Size         : 312 k
Source       : pipx-1.2.1-1.el9.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : epel
Summary      : Install and run Python applications in isolated environments
URL          : https://pypa.github.io/pipx

